# Calculating area with ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, area

This seems deceptively complicated. I have a clip of a large multi-polygon featureclass, and several of the polygons transect the clip barrier. How do I calculate the area of the new bisected polygons without stopping my model, opening up the attribute table, right-clicking on the area field and selecting "Calculate Geometry"? If I sound frustrated it is because I am. There has to be a way to call that function. Also, adding geometry attributes is not desirable because it only does geodesic and not planar calculations.

I am on ArcGIS 10.6

Comment: When you say “multi-polygons” do you mean multiple polygons or multipart polygons?  Are you storing in a geodatabase where areas are automatically calculated?

Comment: I've been asked to re-calculate the areas in these (single-part) polygons for the local projection. There seems to be a pretty big difference between the manually-calculated and the auto-calculated figures. So I guess there isn't a simple way to just insert the command into the model, I gotta go learn some python, huh?

Comment: There should be no difference if your feature class is stored in that local projection.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **"Calculate Field" tool** in the "Data Management Tools" under "Fields".  See:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm

Using the "PYTHON" option, an expression of `!Shape.Area!` works for me.

Comment: Is there no calculate geometry box I can just insert into my model with the parameter "Field" and have the menu look like the manual process? I find his unbelievable. Thanks for your input. I'm not very good at python so my angst is more directed at that (and ESRI)

Comment: Just the “Add Geometry Attributes” tool, I think.  Which is not quite the same.